# ReportExecutionService add datasource?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, reportviewer

Until now, I have been using ReportViewer.LocalReport to generate PDF outputs of locally embedded SSRS Reports, which use predefined datasources that get overridden in my C# application by run-time generated data...

```
// Set the DataSources
report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MilkSolids", this.MilkSolidsTable));
report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Ingredients", this.IngredientsTable));
```

The drawback of course, is that I have to use older versions of BIDS to design the report in. But now I have a new option of using a web reference from our SQL Server 2008 Report Server. This way, I could use BIDS 2008 to write my report in, and then make the report server do the rendering. This works like a charm for the pre-defined datasource; HOWEVER, I cannot find any information on how to override predefined datasources in the ReportExecutionService class.

Is this even possible?
If not, does anyone have another suggestion?